# How to concat the string fields of a struct ignoring the empty strings?

Tags: go, string-concatenation

I am really new to Go, so want some advice.
I have a struct:

```
type Employee struct {
    Name        string
    Designation string
    Department  string
    Salary      int
    Email       string
}
```

I want to concatenate the string fields into a type of employee description.
So that, I can say: 
toString(employee) and get:

```
John Smith Manager Sales john.smith@example.com
```

I tried to fetch each field, check if they are empty and put them in a slice and join them at the end

```
employeeDescArr := make([]string, 0, 4)
if strings.TrimSpace(value) != "" {
    append(employee.GetName(), value)
}...
return strings.Join(employeeDescArr[:], " ")
```

I think this method is very verbose and shows lack of Go skills.
Is it better to use a string Builder instead?
Is there a way to iterate through all fields of a struct in a Reflection way and join them?

Comment: The only reason to use a string builder for something so trivial, is if performance is vital here. I doubt it is. You should always avoid reflection when possible. If what you have works, use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loop through the string fields and collect non-empty strings. Join the fields.

```
func (e *Employee) String() string {
    var parts []string
    for _, s := range []string{e.Name, e.Designation, e.Department, e.Email} {
        if strings.TrimSpace(s) != "" {
            parts = append(parts, s)
        }
    }
    return strings.Join(parts, " ")
}
```

Because the strings.Join function is implemented using strings.Builder, there's no benefit to replacing strings.Join with application code that uses strings.Builder.

Here's how to use reflect to avoid listing the fields in the string function:

```
var stringType = reflect.TypeOf("")

func (e *Employee) String() string {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(e).Elem()
    var parts []string
    for i := 0; i < v.NumField(); i++ {
        f := v.Field(i)
        if f.Type() == stringType {
            s := f.String()
            if strings.TrimSpace(s) != "" {
                parts = append(parts, s)
            }
        }
    }
    return strings.Join(parts, " ")
}
```

If you want to include all fields (include non-strings and empty strings), then you can `fmt.Sprint(e)` to get a string. See https://play.golang.org/p/yntZxQ-Xs6C.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it less verbose by writing an utility function to make the addition with the "non-blank-string" check.

Also, you could make your type implement implement an `String()` method which has the advantage it will make it print as you wish when used in `fmt` print functions.

This `addToString` function is generic so you could reuse it if doing this for other types:

```
func addToString(original string, addition interface{}) string {
    additionStr := fmt.Sprint(addition)
    if additionStr != "" {
        if original != "" {
            original += " "
        }
        original += additionStr
    }
    return original
}
```

Then you can implement it like this, which is not so verbose:

```
type Employee struct {
    Name        string
    Designation string
    Department  string
    Salary      int
    Email       string
}

func (e *Employee) String() string {
    theString := ""
    theString = addToString(theString, e.Name)
    theString = addToString(theString, e.Designation)
    theString = addToString(theString, e.Department)
    theString = addToString(theString, e.Salary)
    theString = addToString(theString, e.Email)
    return theString
}
```

And use it like this:

```
func main() {
    emp := &Employee{
        Name: "Jonh",
        Department: "Some dept",
    }
    fmt.Println(emp.String())
    fmt.Println(emp)
}
```

Which will output:

```
Jonh Some dept 0
Jonh Some dept 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you would want to use the Stringer interface instead. ie:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "strings"
  "strconv"
)
type Employee struct {
    Name        string
    Designation string
    Department  string
    Salary      int
    Email       string
}
func main() {
  emp1:=Employee{Name:"Cetin", Department:"MS", Salary:50}
  emp2:=Employee{Name:"David", Designation:"Designation", Email:"david@nowhere.com"}
  emp3:=Employee{Department:"Space", Salary:10}

  fmt.Println(emp1)
  fmt.Println(emp2)
  fmt.Println(emp3)

}

func (e Employee) String() string {
    var salary string
    if e.Salary > 0 { 
      salary = strconv.Itoa(e.Salary) + " " 
    } else {
      salary = ""
    }
    return strings.TrimSpace(
        strings.TrimSpace(
        strings.TrimSpace(e.Name + " " + e.Designation) + " " +
        e.Department) + " " +
    salary +
        e.Email)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/L8ft7SeXpqt

PS: I later noticed you only want string fields, but didn't remove salary anyway.